# Get url from which a script was called

Tags: php

I have a page on the url `www.example.com/some/info`. 
This page sends a form to a PHP script. 
Is there a way to get this url in the PHP script so that I can redirect to it when the script executes? 
I tried `$_SERVER['REMOTE_HOST']`, but got an undefined index exception.

Edit: I am using Apache's rewrite module so that all the requests are redirected to index.php which then handles resolving them.

Comment: I combined the first and second answers here and got pretty good results: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6768793/php-get-the-full-url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try concept of referral url

```
<?php
    print_r($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
?>
```

Comment: enjoy keep questioning :)

Comment: No, this is not “exactly what you need”. Please do some research on how unreliable the HTTP referer is (that goes for the answering person as well).

Answer (score 1):

Try using `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`

by this,  you will be able to get your current URL.